# INSERT INTO Error

Tags: postgresql, carto

Hey guys I am trying to get the results of a query into a column in my table. The error I received is this ERROR: Quota exceeded by 16KB. I am using cartodb API,

```
INSERT INTO address (distance)
Select ST_Distance_Sphere(c.the_geom,(SELECT the_geom FROM lod_poly ORDER BY the_geom <-> 
c.the_geom LIMIT 1)) From address c
```

Is this a correct query for what I am trying to do?   One other question I have is how can I convert meters into feet within the query ?

Comment: "quota exceeded" would indicate that whatever you are trying to do needs more space than you currently have at cartodb.

Comment: Yes thats what I thought Though I have plenty of space left and I tried the sql on just five records. All I get is a loading screen then nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Perhaps try,

```
VACUUM FULL
```

in the SQL interface. This will clean up and reclaim space from deleted tables. CartoDB does it automatically, but if it hasn't done it in a while, this could help.

After that, check your quota on your dashboard, sometimes VACUUM FULL reveals that you are in fact over. Alternatively, if you are still below, try the INSERT again